# Little program to measure costly operations

Tags: c++, performance

I want to learn about performance impact of different calculations and influences/optimizations like compiler flags, use of SSE, AVX etc.

I'm going to code some small subroutines which will take place in almost every arithmetic operation in a special program, thus good code, portability and performance do! matter.

Insofar the questions:

- is the code below meaningful?
- should it be improved?
- or is 'better' already in the field and i just overlooked it?
- is similar possible in 'C'?

I'm new here and **not** a coder, 'script kiddie' at best, the program is 'picked together' at SO and cppreference, thus 'bear with me' and I beg your pardon for any stupidity or errors.

I have asked the question with a prior version at SO, some tips from there are implemented.

```
// compile with e.g. 
// g++ -O1 timing_operations_2.c -o timing_operations_2 -lm
// impressive differenes with  
// g++ -O9 timing_operations_2.c -o timing_operations_2 -lm
// but think that's reg. supressing code with no further use

// not necessary? 
// #include <algorithm>
// #include <ctime>
#include <iostream> // reg. cout, 
#include <iomanip>  // reg. put_time, setpreision, 
#include <chrono>   // reg. chrono, 
#include <thread>   // reg. thread, 
#include <math.h>   // reg. pow( x, y ), 
 
using namespace std; 
using namespace std::literals; // enables the usage of 24h, 1ms, 1s instead of
                               // e.g. std::chrono::hours(24), accordingly

void slow_motion()
{
        std::cout << "Hello waiter\n" << std::flush;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Hi! in one second I'll die! :-( " << endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = end-start;
    std::cout << "urrrrggghhhh!     took: " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";
}
 
int main()
{
    int amount = 100000;    // size of testfield
    int i = 0;      // counter
    double x1 = 0;      // working value

    std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << std::fixed;

    const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now =
            std::chrono::system_clock::now();
 
        const std::time_t t_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now - 24h);
    std::cout << "24 hours ago, the time was "
        << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t_c), "%F %T.\n") << std::flush;
 
        const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start =
        std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
 
        slow_motion();
 
        const auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
 
        std::cout
        << "Slow calculations took "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << "µs ≈ "
        << (end - start) / 1ms << "ms ≈ " // almost equivalent form of the above, but
        << (end - start) / 1s << "s.\n";  // using milliseconds and seconds accordingly


// preparing testvalues for timing, 

    double testme[amount];

    for( i = 0; i < amount; ++i )
    {
            testme[i] = rand() / pow( 2, 16 );
    }


// timing ' x / 2 ', 
    auto start_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for( i = 0; i < amount; ++i )
    {
        x1 = testme[i] / 2;
//      cout << "' x / 2:     " << x1 << "\n";
    }
    auto end_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = end_1-start_1;
        std::cout
        << "calculating " << amount << " times ' = x / 2 ' took         " 
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_1 - start_1).count() << "µs ≈ "
        << (end_1 - start_1) / 1ms << "ms ≈ " // almost equivalent form of the above, but
        << (end_1 - start_1) / 1s << "s.\n";  // using milliseconds and seconds accordingly


// timing ' x / 2 ', a second time aginst caching influences, 
    start_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for( i = 0; i < amount; ++i )
    {
        x1 = testme[i] / 2;
//      cout << "' x / 2:     " << x1 << "\n";
    }
    end_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = end_1-start_1;
        std::cout
        << "calculating " << amount << " times ' = x / 2 ' took         " 
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_1 - start_1).count() << "µs ≈ "
        << (end_1 - start_1) / 1ms << "ms ≈ " // almost equivalent form of the above, but
        << (end_1 - start_1) / 1s << "s.\n";  // using milliseconds and seconds accordingly


// timing ' x / 3 ', 
    start_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for( i = 0; i < amount; ++i )
    {
        x1 = testme[i] / 3;
//      cout << "' x / 3:     " << x1 << "\n";
    }
    end_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = end_1-start_1;
        std::cout
        << "calculating " << amount << " times ' = x / 3 ' took         " 
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_1 - start_1).count() << "µs ≈ "
        << (end_1 - start_1) / 1ms << "ms ≈ " // almost equivalent form of the above, but
        << (end_1 - start_1) / 1s << "s.\n";  // using milliseconds and seconds accordingly


// timing ' (int)x ', 
    start_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for( i = 0; i < amount; ++i )
    {
        x1 = (int)testme[i];
//      cout << "' (int)x ':     " << x1 << "\n";
    }
    end_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = end_1-start_1;
        std::cout
        << "calculating " << amount << " times ' = (int)x ' took        " 
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_1 - start_1).count() << "µs ≈ "
        << (end_1 - start_1) / 1ms << "ms ≈ " // almost equivalent form of the above, but
        << (end_1 - start_1) / 1s << "s.\n";  // using milliseconds and seconds accordingly


// timing ' pow( 10, x ) ', 
    start_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for( i = 0; i < amount; ++i )
    {
        x1 = pow( 10, testme[i] );
//      cout << "' (int)x ':     " << x1 << "\n";
    }
    end_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = end_1-start_1;
        std::cout
        << "calculating " << amount << " times ' = pow( 10, x ) ' took " 
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_1 - start_1).count() << "µs ≈ "
        << (end_1 - start_1) / 1ms << "ms ≈ " // almost equivalent form of the above, but
        << (end_1 - start_1) / 1s << "s.\n";  // using milliseconds and seconds accordingly

    return ( 0 ); 
}
```

Comment: I don't see any mutexes or `std::atomic` types in your code, so I wouldn't call the things you want to measure "atomic", just "small bits of code".

Comment: @G. Sliepen: 'atomic' - didn't know that it's a reserved word, sorry | 'tag' - I tagged the issue 'C' because it includes the question how to perform such in (pure) 'C'.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 6 → 4. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

[Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

You can, however, in a CPP file (not H file) or inside a function put individual `using std::string;` etc.  (See [SF.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file).)

---

I'm afraid the high-resolution-clock might not work right as it's not a *monotonic* clock.  Which clock is best for this purpose depends on the platform, I'm afraid.  And, I don't think any clock will be good enough for the kind of micro-benchmarks you describe.  You're mentioning *microseconds* in the code, but "some small subroutines which will take place in almost every arithmetic operation" sounds like you need to be using *nanoseconds*.  I would use the CPU-specific cycle counter register to benchmark something like individual arithmetic operations.

If you're going to make a loop to do a primitive operation millions or billions of times, you might get deceptive or even bizarre results, as it will not reflect the mix of instructions as seen in the real code.  The CPU may pipeline the loop with multiple operations in-flight simultaneously, but in real code the operation of interest is mixed with other code.  You can get a completely wrong answer as it relates to the real code, because of differences in pipelining, simultaneous instructions in-flight vs latency of dependant results, and caching.

Comment: hello @JDługosz, thanks for your hints. 'namespace' - implemented | 'monotonic clock' - I'm open for proposals | 'micro-benchmarks' - i'm aware that this is no exact science on modern systems, just want to get an 'idea' | 'nanoseconds' i had in my first try? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69631678/which-operations-are-costly-for-the-cpu-review-a-program-rewrite-for-c - | 'loop different to code mix' - I'm aware of, but while I can't be perfect I have to accept compromises | where is the 'speedometer' program doing such analysis without requiring every coder to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);` _or_ `getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &rr);` depending on whether I want to measure system call times.  I've done simple microbenchmarks by using the `rdtsc` instruction via an intrinsic.  That is the cycle timer on x86.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of repetition here - consider refactoring the timing code so you don't need to write so much to add timing (perhaps pass a lambda to suitable timing function).

This kind of code:

> ```
> for( i = 0; i < amount; ++i )
> {
>     x1 = testme[i] / 2;
> }
> ```

will be optimised away completely by any decent compiler, since the results are never used (the assignment is a *dead write*).   So you're likely not measuring what you think you are (unless you build without optimisation, which will be just as misleading).

Comment: hello @Toby Speight, thank you. 'repetition' - I'm not! a 'pro' | 'lambda' - don't know about | 'dead code' - issue: how to get it 'live', with as less as possible impact on the timings. I don't need 'absolute' timings as I mostly will compare two different algos, '(void)x1;' which elsewhere helped against compiler warnings 'unused' didn't help. | 'optimizations' - funnily 'pow..' isn't optimized away except with -Ofast ??? and 'jitters' between -O5 and -O8? | 'clock_monotonic' - like this: https://people.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/gettime.html ?

Comment: For your code not to be optimised away to nothing, it's important to actually _use_ the result - perhaps `x1 += testme[i] / 2;`, combined with some other use of `x1` outside the loop (printing, perhaps).

Comment: thank you @Toby Speight, would the compiler be dumb enough not! to see that it would be sufficient to calculate only the last element of the array? as the prior results results would be overwritten by the next calculation.

Comment: That is why I suggested `+=`, to ensure that all the values get used.

Comment: thank you @Toby Speight, overlooked that detail ... have to be aware that the timing will have 2 operations in the loop ('+' and '/') and need to use small values in testme, otherwise x1 will overflow ... improving ...